# Vue JS - variable from javascript module is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api, vee-validate

I created a small module as a validator inspired from vee-validate and I would like to use this in conjunction with the composition api.
I have a list of errorMessages that are stored in a reactive array, however when I retrieve this variable in my vue component, despite the error messages being stored in the array accordingly, the variable is not updating in the vue template.

I’m not very savvy with this so I might not be concise with my explanation. The refs in the module seem to be working properly.
Can someone kindly indicate what I might be doing wrong? I'm completely stuck and I don't know how else I can proceed.

Validator.js (Npm module - located in node_modules)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'
import {ref} from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI)

class Validator {
….

register({fieldName, rules, type}) {
    if (!fieldName || rules === null || rules === undefined) {
      console.error('Please pass in fieldName and rules');
      return false;
    }
    let errorMessages = ref([]);
    // define callback for pub-sub
    const callback = ({id, messages}) => {
      if (fieldId === id) {
        errorMessages.value = Object.assign([], messages);
        console.log(errorMessages.value); // this contains the value of the error messages.
      }
    };
    return {
      errorMessages,
    };
  }
……
```

InputField.vue

```html
<template>
  <div :style="{'width': fieldWidth}" class="form-group">
    <label :for="fieldName">
      <input
        ref="inputField"
        :type="type"
        :id="fieldName"
        :name="fieldName"
        :class="[{'field-error': apiError || errorMessages.length > 0}, {'read-only-input': isReadOnly}]"
        @input="handleInput"
        v-model="input"
        class="form-input"/>
    </label>
    <div>
      <p class="text-error">{{errorMessages}}</p> // Error messages not displaying
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {ref, watch} from '@vue/composition-api';
  import Validator from "validator";

  export default {
    props: {
      fieldTitle: {
        required: true
      },
      fieldName: {
        required: true
      },
      type: {
        required: true
      },
      rules: {
        default: 'required'
      }
    },
    setup(props) {
      // The error messages are returned in the component but they are not reactive. Therefore they only appear after its re-rendered.
      const {errorMessages, handleInput, setFieldData} = Validator.register(props);

      return {
        errorMessages,
        handleInput,
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Vue.Set()`, it directly triggers related values to be updated

Comment: I had a brief look at Vue.Set(), but I didn't quite understand where I should apply this in my scenario.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Validator.register()` directly destructures `props`, which [removes the reactivity from the resulting values](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#destructuring-reactive-state).

#### Solution

Use [`toRefs(props)`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#torefs) to create an object of `ref`s for each prop, and pass that to `Validator.register()`:

```js
import { toRefs } from 'vue'
                       
Validator.register(toRefs(props))
```

Then update `Validator.register()` to unwrap the refs where needed:

```js
class Validator {
  register({ fieldName, rules, type }) {
                                                        
    if (!fieldName.value || rules.value === null || rules.value === undefined) {
      console.error('Please pass in fieldName and rules');
      return false;
    }
    ⋮
  }
}
```